# App Engine default credentials stopped working on local dev server

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth, google-cloud-vision

I'm running app engine locally, with the Google vision API.  I'm using the application default credentials for OAuth and building the API client to do label detection.  Whenever I create the object it will refresh the credentials

```
DISCOVERY_URL = 'https://{api}.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version={apiVersion}'

class VisionApi(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.vision = self._create_client()

    def _create_client(self):
        credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
        return discovery.build(
            'vision', 'v1', credentials=credentials,
            discoveryServiceUrl=DISCOVERY_URL)
```

This worked just fine yesterday, and I haven't changed it.  When I try to use it today, it attempts to get the credentials twice, and then I get the following 401 error:

```
INFO     2017-08-16 18:12:14,228 discovery.py:863] URL being requested: POST https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?alt=json
INFO     2017-08-16 18:12:14,228 transport.py:157] Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
WARNING  2017-08-16 18:12:14,237 urlfetch_stub.py:504] Stripped prohibited headers from URLFetch request: ['content-length']
INFO     2017-08-16 18:12:14,542 transport.py:185] Refreshing due to a 401 (attempt 1/2)
WARNING  2017-08-16 18:12:14,544 urlfetch_stub.py:504] Stripped prohibited headers from URLFetch request: ['content-length']
INFO     2017-08-16 18:12:14,823 transport.py:185] Refreshing due to a 401 (attempt 2/2)
WARNING  2017-08-16 18:12:14,826 urlfetch_stub.py:504] Stripped prohibited headers from URLFetch request: ['content-length']
```

`HttpError: <HttpError 401 when requesting https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?alt=json returned "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.">`

Why was this working yesterday but isn't working today?  I understand that I can go the route of using server-to-server credentials, but it worked without that and I would prefer to continue using the API without that.

Comment: I think this is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45735933/error-connecting-to-cloud-sql-from-jdbc-appengine-local-dev-server, which is an SO question about possibly the same issue occuring with a java app on the local dev server trying to connect to cloud sql. Suddenly stopped working in the last 24 hours (still unanswered).